# Response encoded in GZIP is unable to decode with Android

Tags: android, gzip

Here's what I receive from the server:

```
  ��������������V�M1U�RJ11L�HN��H30H220I��00���HMN�012OU�Q�,I�-V������֢�25������
```

The same response, but through a sniffer

```
V�M1U�RJ11L�HN��H30H220I��00���HMN�012OU�Q�,I�-V����
```

It is GZIP for sure, I can decode it through the sniffer, it has `Content-Encoding GZIP`.
I'm trying to decode it like this:

```
private static InputStream unzip(InputStream data){
try { data = new GZIPInputStream(data); } catch (IOException e) {       e.printStackTrace(); }
  return data;
}
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?
This is how I get the data:

```
if (isEncoded && result.length() > 0){ Header header =     response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding"); if  (header.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")){ result = unzip(result); } }
```

Comment: From what kind of server? What kind of client in use? Any protocol?

Comment: @greenapps Apache server, setup not by me. Client  is AndroidHttpClient,  
import android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient; protocol is http

Comment: Apache server with php? Or what? Well show complete code. And if you have an url that we can use too...